# successCallback of fullCalendar v5.11.0 is not returned

Tags: javascript, ajax, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I am having trouble because the successCallback of fullCalendar v5.11.0 may not return.
I would like to know how to solve the problem.

I am using fullCalendar v5.11.0,
I am creating a web application that displays data obtained from Google Calendar.

The app is working without any problems, but
In rare cases, the page freezes when displayed.

After calling successCallback in the code shown below, it freezes.

```
function onEvents(fetchInfo, successCallback, failureCallback) {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/user/ajax_get_calendar/',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {
      start: fetchInfo.startStr,
      end: fetchInfo.endStr,
    },
    dataType: 'json',
  }).done(response => {
    successCallback(response.events);
  });
}
```

Comment: So...did you check in the browser console for any errors? Did you check the Network tool tool to see if the AJAX request succeeded, and what exactly it returned? Maybe you returned too many events? Or maybe it didn't return at all? You claim the "freezing" occurs _after_ successCallback is called, but how exactly are you verifying that? Is there an error with a stack trace? Did you use a debugger? There's so little meaningful information in your question that it's very difficult for us to do much more than guess. See also [ask] and how to make a [mre] of the issue. You can [edit] your post.